# DFA Minimization by Hopcroft algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, automata

```
P := {F, Q \ F};
W := {F};
while (W is not empty) do
     choose and remove a set A from W
     for each c in ∑ do
          let X be the set of states for which a transition on c leads to a state in A
          for each set Y in P for which X ∩ Y is nonempty do
               replace Y in P by the two sets X ∩ Y and Y \ X
               if Y is in W
                    replace Y in W by the same two sets
               else
                    if |X ∩ Y| <= |Y \ X|
                         add X ∩ Y to W
                    else
                         add Y \ X to W
          end;
     end;
end;
```

I made a converting from DFA to minimal DFA by using Hopcroft algorithm.
I find a pseudo code from Wikipedia by this link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft.27s_algorithm
and I made python code to converting dfa.

```
def minimize(self,dfa):
    P = [set(dfa.finalstates),dfa.states.difference(set(dfa.finalstates))]
    W = [set(dfa.finalstates)]

    while len(W) != 0:
        A = W[0]
        W.remove(A)
        X = set()
        for c in dfa.alphabet:
            for from_state, to_state in dfa.transitions.items():
                for toNum, value in to_state.items():
                    if c in value and toNum in A:
                        X.update(set([from_state]))
        for Y in P:
            if not X.intersection(Y) == set():
                P.append(X.intersection(Y))
                P.append(Y.difference(X))
                if Y in W:
                    W.append(X.intersection(Y))
                    W.append(Y.difference(X))
                    W.remove(Y)
                else :
                    if len(X.intersection(Y)) <= len (Y.difference(X)):
                        W.append(X.intersection(Y))
                        #W.remove(Y)
                    else :
                        W.append(Y.difference(X))
                        #W.remove(Y)
                P.remove(Y)

    print P,W
```

my DFA consists of five indicators,

```
dfa.states = set() of states.
dfa.startstate = int number of start state number
dfa.finalstates = list structure consisting of final states
dfa.transitions = dictionary structure of dfa transitions.
ex) {from state : {to state1 : set of character to go to state1 , to state 2 : set of charac...}}
dfa.alphabet = set of dfa alphabets.
```

I don't know why this algorithm not work my code, is any problem in my code?

Comment: Ok. 1) What exactly doesn't work? Does it give you an error, or does it just not produce the correct output? What output do you expect, and how does the program output differ from that? 2) What is the `dfa` object? Do you have the code for it? What is a "state"? Is it a list, int, string, etc?

Comment: Too bad this question is closed, because I'm having exactly the same problem.